# Inline-editable list item doubling as link to detail page

Tags: inline-edit

I have a relatively simple list of events where all information (name and date) is editable inline:

[image: Inline-editable list item]

[image: Edit mode]

As can be seen in the screenshot, I currently have a "Details" button for heading into a more detailed view. I have other similar lists in the application where each item does *not* have a more detailed view, and I naturally seek a consistent design where every list of this kind is inline-editable.

How can I get rid of the "Details" button without sacrificing the ability to edit the item's information inline?

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE! There have been numerous questions about inline editing asked over the years. I'm sure there's a solution in the archive to be searched and found.

Comment: So currently, does clicking "details" puts the text field in edit mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. but you should ask yourself this question: Would the user to more likely to click the link into the details or edit the link?

You want the hit area of your more likely action to be larger. Your current solution place a lot of emphasis on easy editing.

If you combine the link and edit together, you're now likely emphasizing the link over the edit option.

e.g.

> [image: JIRA inline edit with link]
>
> Taken from JIRA project management interface

Screenshot is missing the cursor, but essentially clicking anywhere on the url takes you to that link and you have to click on the edit icon to edit.

I think in majority of cases, it'll be more likely for users to click through the link, but editing does take more work with this approach.

Comment: Yes, I see now that what I am trying to do is not going to work. I'll go with the two-step editing – thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, our team finds JIRA's behavior described above infuriating because we do a lot more editing than linking. Some fields that are not linkable can be edited by clicking on the field, but linkable fields cause a lot of accidental links. So if you're going to provide this feature, I'd suggest you be really sure that linking is a common activity before changing the "edit on click" behavior that non-linkable fields will have. If linking is less common, then consider making an additional action button to navigate to the detail page instead of having it be a hyperlink.